# while changing data to time series the year column is getting copied in first few rows

Tags: r, time-series

My data has 39 rows and 13 columns, 1st being year and the remaining are months. while converting it to time series I am facing trouble. my data looks like:
[part of original data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTccm.png)
I already tried:

```
SLP <- as.matrix(SLP_anamoly_series, nrow = 39, ncol = 12)
set.seed(12)
SLP.df <- as.data.frame(SLP)
months <- format(seq.Date(as.Date("2013-01-01"), as.Date("2013-12-01"), 
                      by = "month"), format = "%b")
colnames(SLP.df) <- months
SLP.df$Year <- seq(1979, 2017) # setting as variable and not rowname

#Melting data, so we have dataframe with 39*12 rows
library(reshape2)
SLP.df <- melt(SLP.df, id.vars = "Year")

#ordering the observations by date:
SLP.df$Date <- as.Date(paste(SLP.df$Year, SLP.df$variable, "01", sep = "-"),
                     format = ("%Y-%b-%d"))
SLP.df <- SLP.df[order(SLP.df$Date), ]
#applying ts() and showing the desired behaviour
SLP.df.ts <- ts(SLP.df$value, start=c(1979,1), end=c(2017,1), frequency=12)
```

In the output, the data is getting converted as a ts class but the year column is getting pasted in the beginning and NA values are getting incorporated.["NA" getting incorporated in the months attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwRo5.png) 
Also, the data is shifted  like below:
[The Jan column getting the years as data and the values shifting to feb and so on][3]
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this without reshaping the data.

```
SLP.ts <- ts(as.vector(t(SLP)), 
                  start=c(1979,1), end=c(2017,12), frequency=12)
```

Where `SLP` is you `matrix` with 12 columns.

Demo with dummy data:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data_frame(jan = rnorm(11), feb = rnorm(11), mar = rnorm(11), apr = rnorm(11),
                 may = rnorm(11), jun = rnorm(11), jul = rnorm(11), aug = rnorm(11),
                 sep = rnorm(11), oct = rnorm(11), nov = rnorm(11), dec = rnorm(11)) 
df
# A tibble: 11 × 12
#         jan         feb         mar         apr        may        jun         jul        aug
#         <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1  -0.7277503  0.49203901 -1.13683935  0.44493938  0.9787063 -0.5965367  0.29731164 -1.2694916
# 2   2.0578348  0.38561186 -1.51999945 -0.59548193  0.3029656  1.1741675  0.43631169  1.3844318
# 3   1.3249527  0.09741269 -0.31423972  0.47217778  0.7478160 -1.8150642 -0.34418245 -2.6152873
# 4  -1.3849326 -0.42547285  1.30308770 -0.94788520  1.0027448  1.1740929  0.82583414 -1.2775077
# 5  -0.3177837 -1.79757244  1.26156967 -0.18426188 -0.5292503 -0.1482064  0.65681287 -0.4899618
# 6   0.1783239  0.08827373  0.09984112 -0.26299795 -0.4508580  2.0388265 -1.86185049  0.2263487
# 7  -1.7751816 -0.35399751  0.59095293 -0.99107748  0.4541772 -0.3005032  0.41004362 -0.1532398
# 8   1.4083479  0.90696406  1.10822694  2.97771956  0.7045538 -0.9063333 -1.30249178 -0.9727064
# 9   1.1097756 -1.79374219 -0.28359382  2.03726012  0.4181745  1.4613433  3.08177756 -0.9129661
# 10  0.5645198  0.18942828  0.57254031  0.03366888 -0.5167837  0.9518762  1.85161175 -0.1574078
# 11 -0.1483672 -0.31044439  1.05764639  1.03100621 -0.9845712 -0.8245992 -0.05860948 -0.8921633
# ... with 4 more variables: sep <dbl>, oct <dbl>, nov <dbl>, dec <dbl>

SLP <- as.matrix(df)

SLP.ts <- ts(as.vector(t(SLP)), 
             start=c(1979,1), end=c(1989,12), frequency=12)
SLP.ts
#               Jan         Feb         Mar         Apr         May         Jun         Jul         Aug
# 1979 -0.72775035  0.49203901 -1.13683935  0.44493938  0.97870627 -0.59653672  0.29731164 -1.26949164
# 1980  2.05783479  0.38561186 -1.51999945 -0.59548193  0.30296562  1.17416747  0.43631169  1.38443180
# 1981  1.32495271  0.09741269 -0.31423972  0.47217778  0.74781602 -1.81506422 -0.34418245 -2.61528729
# 1982 -1.38493258 -0.42547285  1.30308770 -0.94788520  1.00274483  1.17409292  0.82583414 -1.27750774
# 1983 -0.31778370 -1.79757244  1.26156967 -0.18426188 -0.52925034 -0.14820640  0.65681287 -0.48996183
# 1984  0.17832394  0.08827373  0.09984112 -0.26299795 -0.45085804  2.03882653 -1.86185049  0.22634867
# 1985 -1.77518164 -0.35399751  0.59095293 -0.99107748  0.45417718 -0.30050318  0.41004362 -0.15323982
# 1986  1.40834791  0.90696406  1.10822694  2.97771956  0.70455384 -0.90633330 -1.30249178 -0.97270635
# 1987  1.10977565 -1.79374219 -0.28359382  2.03726012  0.41817454  1.46134334  3.08177756 -0.91296614
# 1988  0.56451981  0.18942828  0.57254031  0.03366888 -0.51678368  0.95187622  1.85161175 -0.15740777
# 1989 -0.14836721 -0.31044439  1.05764639  1.03100621 -0.98457119 -0.82459916 -0.05860948 -0.89216334
# Cols Sept-Dec not shown here
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but when i run it, it gives the same output. Which is  Jan 1979 observation is 1979, Feb 1980 observation is 1980, March 1981 is 1981 and so on. Any idea on what's happening?

Comment: @AshritaJohnson I've added an example with dummy data. Not sure where your issue is. Pls accept the answer by clicking the tick (check mark) on left under the vote arrows and also uproot it if this helps. Thanks!

Comment: I was still not able to, it works absolutely fine with random numbers. I am not sure what is happening there.